# How to show/reuse the same view (Alert) in SwiftUI from all ViewModels in case of an error/message?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject

I have been trying to reuse an `Alert` from a `BaseView` (SwiftUI) that can be shown by all View Models in my project so I can avoid boilerplate code.

For this I created two Views (`BaseView` and `BaseLoginView`) and two View Models (`BaseViewModel` and `LoginViewModel`)

I realized that you just can't create a `BaseViewModel` and implement `ObservableObject` because all `@Published` variables on the child ViewModel will not fire any event so it seems that the `ObservableObject` interface must be implemented on the final ViewModel, which in this case is `LoginViewModel`.

But this leads to another problem: the `BaseView` this way can't have an `@ObservedObject var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel` because the `BaseViewModel` doesn't conform to `ObservableObject`. And the `@ObservedObject` is needed to access the boolean bindings with `$`.

This is what I a tried so far:

#### 1 - `BaseView`

```swift
struct BaseView<Content: View>: View {

    @ObservedObject var baseViewModel: BaseViewModel

    let content: Content

    init(vm: BaseViewModel, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.baseViewModel = vm
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
        }
       .alert(isPresented: self.$baseViewModel.showMessage) {
           Alert(title: Text(self.baseViewModel.messageTitle), message: Text(self.baseViewModel.messageText), dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
       }
    }
}
```

#### `LoginView` -> Creates View Model and passes it to base View

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {

    @ObservedObject var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    @State private var username: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    let textFieldHeight = CGFloat(60)
    let textFieldPadding = CGFloat(15)

    init() {
        self.loginViewModel = LoginViewModel()
    }

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                BaseView(vm: self.loginViewModel) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                        Text(self.loginViewModel.myTest)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.loginViewModel.login()
                    }) {
                        Text("Login")
                    }
                }.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### `BaseViewModel`

```swift
import Foundation

class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var showMessage: Bool = false
    @Published var messageTitle : String = ""
    @Published var messageText : String = ""

    public func showMessage(title: String, text: String) {
       self.messageTitle = title
       self.messageText = text
       self.showMessage = true
    }
}
```

#### `LoginViewModel`

```swift
import Foundation

class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel {

    @Published var myTest : String = "Hello"

    func login() {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.myTest = "Bye"
//            self.showMessage(title: "Invalid Data", text: "Please fill all fields!")
        }
    }
}
```

My `ContentView` that I created in a new project:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        //Text("Hello, World!")
        LoginView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The problem is if I update the `showMessage` it works but changing only the `myTest` string to "Bye" doesn't update the view. It will only update if I also update a value that is published in the `BaseViewModel`. Why is that?

How can I solve this problem and avoid boilerplate code?

Comment: In provided code snapshot `myTest` is not used anywhere in view, why do you expect it should update anything?

Comment: @Asperi sorry I deleted the line code by accident while cleaning the example it is now inside the VStack in the LoginView. Please feel free to try the code

Comment: @Steve I tried your code and it's updating text to 'bye' when we click on login button

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati sorry you are right it updates in this case. It just doesn't update the view if we only change a value that is published in LoginViewModel. 
In this case it will only work if we also update a value in the BaseViewModel. I just updated the sample and now you only need to copy and paste to try it

Comment: @Asperi I updated the sample to correctly reproduce the issue sorry.

Comment: It works fine here (after some compiler error fixed). Xcode 11.4. So can't advise anything.

Comment: @Asperi the old code didn't have the problem I reported. If you try to comment the self.showMessage(title: "Invalid Data", text: "Please fill all fields!") in LoginViewModel and leave self.myTest = "Bye" the view will not update. I updated my sample and it now has the issue and is error free. P.S: I am on Xcode 11.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update `myTest` property wrapper and forcefully call Base-class objectwillchange publisher.

```
@Published var myTest : String = "Hello" {
        willSet {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
```

## Note: @Published property wrapper is not working incase of inherited class.

I hope this is something that will be fixed in future releases as the objectWillChange.send() is a lot of boilerplate to maintain.

Comment: After several tries your code seems to be the only one that works it's not pretty but it works, I have been pulling my hair out because of this problem. Is there any bug report that I should follow to check when this issue will get fixed? I am accepting your answer Thank you